# How to prune cherry tree to grow evenly?

Tags: trees, pruning

I have a cherry tree that until September was overshadowed by much larger trees. As a result the tree has no growth on one side. I took the larger trees down and had hoped that this season would bring some fresh shoots, but it looks like this at the moment:

[image: lopsided cherry tree]

It looks like the tree previously had branches on that side that were removed badly at one point:

[image: branches badly removed]

What can I do to encourage more even growth?

Comment: Where is the south? In which side the tree has full sun? To me the tree in background are too large to have a evenly growing cherry tree. The bottom part was pruned badly (it seems that you had some problem with space, so you forced the branches to go again in the center and on top). And your raised bed is too near to the trunk (for a cherry tree). You cannot control too much the nature. I think you should remove some constrains (e.g. the form or a free space around the tree).

Comment: The photo is facing south, so the tree in the background is almost directly south of the cherry tree. There were previously two similar height trees where the raised bed is now, completely overshadowing the cherry tree. All of that was fully established when I moved here in September so I have done nothing other than remove the large trees and added the sleepers.